# How to show tabs of open files across the top of VSCode?

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-code

It seems that I've fat-fingered some hotkey and my top tabs in VSCode have disappeared.

I miss them terribly. How do I configure VSCode to show tabs of open files across the top of the window?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Open the command palette using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and execute `View: Toggle Tab Visibility`:

[image: toggle tab visibility command]

Answer (score 1):

You probably set the "showTabs" setting to false. To fix this, open user settings: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and type in "user settings" and select the "Open User Settings" option.

Find the line that looks something similar to:

```
  "workbench.editor.showTabs": false,
```

and delete it. Save the file, and you should see your tabs again.

If that is not the setting, read through your settings file and see if there is something else that may be causing the issue.