# How can I list open editors in the list bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Somehow, after updating Code, I no longer see the list of open editors in the top bar.

[image: Example here.].

If you look at the bitmap above, you can see in the list of open editors that I have six files being edited, but only the active one is displayed in the top bar. Unless I look at the file explorer on the left, I cannot see what other files are being edited.

The problem is that when I minimize the file explorer:

[image: example here]

... I can't see the other files. The edit **used** to show each file as a tab at the top, but for the life of me, I can't find what setting that would be, or even if it is a setting.

Does anyone have any idea what that setting would be called? I don't know the name of this feature, so finding a setting for it is difficult.

Comment: `"workbench.editor.showTabs": true`?  See also: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface  Might be something with editor groups.

Comment: That was it, thanks. I have no idea how that got changed, it certainly wasn't anything I did manually. Also, thanks for the link, as you can probably tell, I'm still getting started with Code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show tabs of open files across the top of VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744032/how-to-show-tabs-of-open-files-across-the-top-of-vscode)

Answer (score 5):

Go to View -> Open View

[image: Go to the View menu and click Open View]

Then click "Open Editors"

[image: Click "Open Editors"]

That worked for me, I hope it works for you.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

I tried the suggestion by Bacon Bits and it worked for me. Go to settings and search on 'workbench'. If your value for "workbench.editor.showTabs": is false then change it to true. If your value is already true then this is not your answer and something else is wrong.